# Integrating jBehave + Junit + Springs + Selenium

Tags: java, spring, selenium-webdriver, jbehave

I have one integration-test written in JUNIT 4.8.2 (Selenium and Spring annotations are used in it).

Now i have to integrate these with JBehave. How this can be achieved?

My TestClass looks something like below

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:config/applicationContext.xml" })
@Category(IntegrationTest.class)
public class SeleniumIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private ImplementationClass implClass;

    @Test
    public void testIntegration() {

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = 
              new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ConfigurationUtils.class);
        baseURL = context.getBean(Configuration.class).getBaseUrl();

        SeleniumImpl selenium = new SeleniumImpl(FIREFOX.driver());
        selenium.OpenURL(baseURL);
    }
}
```

*Currently i am running the tests thru command line by the command* **mvn integration-test.**
Now, how do i integrate JBehave to it. (The WebDriver of JBehave has to be overridden) and run the JBehave thru command line

Answer (score 0):

Map all your test methods with a story. Check [this](https://github.com/ashrafuzzaman/Simple-jbehave-example) for a JBehave example to get started.

Comment: JBehave uses **WebDriverProvider** but i am setting the Slenium **WebDriver** inside the code. Now, _how to override the JBehave's  WebDriverProvider(FireFox driver for suppose) with Selenium's WebDriver(HTML unit driver for suppose)_?

Comment: i wonder, why do you need to override? You can set your webdriver in your step class itself. You can check [this example][1] to get a clear view.
[1] https://github.com/ashrafuzzaman/Simple-jbehave-example